# Динамически изменять размер лого основываясь на размере видео

Tags: python, moviepy

Видео бывают очень разного размера, а лого всегда 130х90. Помогите, пожалуйста, написать алгоритм динамического масштабирования лого на основе размера видео. А то сейчас очень криво сделано...Размер этот может быть от 250 по х до 1280, например

```
import moviepy.editor as mp

video = mp.VideoFileClip('vid.mp4')
w,h = video.size
vid_x_size, vid_y_size = video.size
logo_size_x = 190
logo_size_y = 35
duration = video.duration
R1 = logo_size_x  #изначальный масштаб соответствует оригинальному лого

if w<250:
    R1 = logo_size_x*0.7
elif w>480:
    R1 = logo_size_x*0.8
elif w>700:
    R1 = logo_size_x*1.7
elif w>900:
    R1 = logo_size_x*2.3
elif w>1050:
    R1 = logo_size_x*2.7
elif w>1250:
    R1 = logo_size_x*3.5  
elif w>1350:
    R1 = logo_size_x*4 
elif w>1650:
    R1 = logo_size_x*5 
elif w>1900:
    R1 = logo_size_x*6

fin_list = [video]

logo = (mp.ImageClip("logo.png") 
            .resize(width=R1)
            .set_opacity(0.7)
            .set_start(1)
            .set_duration(duration-1)
            .margin(right=8, top=8, opacity=0)
            .set_pos((10, 10)))

fin_list.append(logo)
final = mp.CompositeVideoClip(fin_list, use_bgclip=True)
final.write_videofile("vid_logo.mp4", fps=24, codec='libx264')
```

Comment: во всех `elif` замените `>` на `<`

Comment: да, но всё равно приходится прописывать в коде каждый шаг по размеру видео

Comment: попробуйте умножить `logo_size_x` на `w`, а потом поделите на какое-то число, к примеру `300`

Comment: Если нарисовать график по вашим коэффициентам, то он выйдет почти линейным. `R1 = logo_size_x * w / 330`